# Understanding the implementation of T-Net in the PointNet model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, point-clouds

I reading the [PointNet paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00593) and I am trying to understand how I should implement the `T-Net` block of the model (it is the same idea for both input and feature transform). All the PyTorch implementations I have looked at, do the same thing this snippet is taken from [here](https://github.com/fxia22/pointnet.pytorch/blob/master/pointnet/model.py):

```py
class STNkd(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, k=64):
        super(STNkd, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(k, 64, 1)
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv1d(64, 128, 1)
        self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv1d(128, 1024, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, k*k)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1024)
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm1d(512)
        self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm1d(256)

        self.k = k

    def forward(self, x):
        batchsize = x.size()[0]
        x = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.bn3(self.conv3(x)))
        x = torch.max(x, 2, keepdim=True)[0]
        x = x.view(-1, 1024)

        x = F.relu(self.bn4(self.fc1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.bn5(self.fc2(x)))
        x = self.fc3(x)

        iden = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.eye(self.k).flatten().astype(np.float32))).view(1,self.k*self.k).repeat(batchsize,1)
        if x.is_cuda:
            iden = iden.cuda()
        x = x + iden
        x = x.view(-1, self.k, self.k)
        return x
```

I am able to follow all the steps, until the `iden` part. Basically, if I understand correctly, they **add an identity matrix to the regressed one**. Does this make sense?

According to the paper:

1. The output matrix is initialized as an identity matrix.
2. The feature transformation matrix to be close to orthogonal matrix

The second point is clear. Just add `(I - xx^T)^2` in the final loss. The first point seems unclear to me. I think the word *initialized* is a bad one, since this matrix is actually **predicted by the network**. Adding at each step (even at inference) an identity matrix, doesn't sound like an *initialization*.

Can someone fill these gaps between the paper and the implementation?

Some of the PyTorch implementations I have checked:

1. [Implementation No 1](https://github.com/fxia22/pointnet.pytorch/blob/master/pointnet/model.py)
2. [Implementation No 2](https://github.com/itberrios/3D/blob/main/point_net/point_net.py)

Comment: you'll need the right understanding of "linear algebra" for these things. I don't have enough of that. -- making the network infer a "residual" (resnet) seems to be a common tactic. it's a similar idea to a control loop getting fed the difference between target and actual. if they add an identity matrix, then perhaps the basic output (result of matrix mul) should look *mostly* like an identity, but with some modifications (residual). -- that's not so much a programming question as a neural networks question. perhaps you'll get better answers on another stack exchange.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the answer. So basically, the regressed matrix should like a slightly modified identity one and these slightly modifications are what regressed? This now makes sense.